# Is there an efficient algorithm to verify that a finite code is uniquely decodeable?

Tags: algorithm, theory, information-theory

Is there an efficient algorithm to verify that a finite binary code is uniquely decodeable?

Let's say we have an alphabet of symbols `A` and some encoding of those symbols `C`. How do we check quickly that there are no distinct strings `s1` and `s2` made up of symbols in `A` that have the same encoding in `C`?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for something faster than the [Sardinas Patterson algorithm?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm)

Comment: I just wanted to know what algorithms there were that solved this problem. If there are faster algorithms, then I'd love to know about them too.